# GCP Vertex AI - Insight from Text Data

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp, google-cloud-vertex-ai

We are trying to use GCP's Vertex AI to extract insights, summary and the query against the Text Data that we upload. Is it possible to do that? We are simply looking for ways to  extract information from our custom Text data through NLP. Will Vertex AI can help us in this regard? We just want to transfer learning of some pre-trained language model to our custom text data and use it to answer our queries against the custom text data.